# If I make a simple gui for my python script, would it affect its efficiency?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I want to make a web crawler that checks URL for data, If i make a simple Gui that would make the script easier to look for variables in that data, Would adding code for the gui make my web crawler less efficient ?

I need the crawler to be as efficient as possible, to be able to process data as fast as possible. Would making a gui for this Python script, hinder the performance of the web crawler ?

Comment: Unless you update the gui with the underlying algorithm, not much. You need to use two *threads*: a gui thread and a processing thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you clearly separate your GUI logic from your processing logic, it shouldn't. As is the case with all optimization though, the best approach is to make the thing work first, then profile and optimize if it isn't performing fast enough for you.

I would suggest you first create your web crawler and forget the GUI. Profile and optimize it if you think it's too slow. Build it with the goal of it being an importable library. Once that works from the command line, then create your GUI front-end and bind your web crawling library functions and classes to the buttons and fields in your GUI. That clear separation should ensure that the GUI logic doesn't interfere with the performance of the web crawling. In particular, try to avoid updating the GUI with status information in the middle of the web crawling.

Comment: Makes total sense, but why i like your answer is to avoid updating the GUI with status info in the middle of the process, that's very helpful. Thank you kind sir !